# Gracefully stop a Timer callback worker thread

Tags: .net, windows-services, timer, threadpool

I am using `System.Threading.Timer` in my Windows service and locking the callback method using `Monitor.TryEnter`, so it's non-reentrant. Inside the callback, I am looping over some database objects (Linq to SQL entities) and performing some IO tasks. On each iteration of the loop, I am changing some properties of entity to flag it as processed. After the loop exits, I call `SubmitChanges` on the datacontext, which persists the changes to the database. The following problem arises: if the service is stopped while the callback is executing, some of the IO tasks may have already been performed, but the records have not been flagged as processed in the database (i.e. SubmitChanges has not been called yet) -- clearly, not what I want to happen. Somehow, I need to communicate to the callback worker thread that the OnStop event has fired to allow it to submit changes and wrap things up. How best to do this?

Comment: I assumed that your concern is that by killing the timer you'll kill your timer callback function execution, is that correct?

Comment: Not quite. I should be more clear; I realize that stopping the timer just stops it from firing again but doesn't kill the callback method. However, some of the IO tasks may be long-running -- perhaps several minutes. I don't want the user (or system) to forcefully abort the process if it's taking too long. I'd rather the service it self finish it gracefully.

Comment: Well, service control has RequestMoreTime() method or something like that (I am speaking from the memory) with which you can prolong your service stopping time and still not appear to be hanged to SCM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st decide if you will finish the tasks that callback performs or you will rollback them.  So if you decide to finish the tasks, you will perform the callback to the end.  Time should be canceled in OnStop already.  If you will go with the second option (rollback) your code will look something like that:

```
bool shouldAbort=false;

TimerProc()
{
     Step1();
     if (shouldAbort)
     {
         UndoStep1();
         return;
     }
     Step2();
     if (shouldAbort)
     {
         UndoStep2();
         UndoStep1();  //  or vice versa, depending on your operations
         return;
     }
     // ...
}
```

in OnStop()

```
timer.Stop();  //  don't worry here - your TimerProc() WILL finish
shouldAbort=true;
```

Comment: if you have worries about TimerProc() not completing, use AutoResetEvent and WaitOne() on it after killing the timer, and Set() the event at the end of the TimerProc()

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I *am* stopping the timer in OnStop: timer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0) -- am using the Timer from the Threading namespace. But I also want to signal to the callback thread to wrap up quickly (no rollback). Perhaps a scenario that makes the need more apparent is a shutdown event.

Comment: There are two Antonys: one who wants the task to wrap up quickly, and other that doesn't want long i/o tasks to be forcibly killed.  One should give up, let's give them some time to decide :)

Comment: Hehe.. maybe. It's really a sequence of several distinct IO processes: create a file, FTP a file, send some emails, perform some db tasks, etc. Each task has a completion flag associated with it in the db. Both Antonys want to interrupt the sequence, not an individual IO operation. Hope this clears things up.

Comment: So, hm, where's the problem.  Raise some flag as suggested, exit, and that's it?  Hm, am I missing something here?

Comment: I can set some variables at the class level and check them before performing each task. Do you see any issues with that since I am accessing these variables from a background thread? I've asked the question b/c multithreading is not my strength -- I come from a web dev background. Thanks again.

Comment: No, there will be no issues with the variables, they are shared between threads.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). Have a read of the [Task Cancellation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396.aspx) page. This would give you a way to create worker threads that can tidy up cleanly in response to a cancellation, if I've understood your needs correctly.

Comment: Looks very interesting, but unfortunately I am still using Framework 3.5 :(